Removing "all" entries of Type from an array (Godot Editor)
I realized I wanted a way to safeguard for null entries, not only in the inspector but via code as well. After looking through the docs and not really understanding how to make use of .any(), .all(), .filter(), or .reduce(). I ended up writing this bit of code to iterate backwards through the array so that removing an entry would not result in an "out of bounds exception". It works with no issues as far as I can tell, but I was wondering if there might be a better way? Or how could one of the mentioned functions above be used in place?
Edit: Just realized the type can be inferred as well, so just wanted to update this to relfect that. It doesnt just need to be "null"
@export var faces: Array[Texture2D]:
    set(value): faces = remove_empty(value, null)

func remove_entries(array: Array, entry) -> Array:
    for n in range(len(array), 0, -1):
        if array[n-1] == entry:
            array.remove_at(n-1)
    return array

Thanks for any feedback.

Actually, at the same time, to save time doing extensive research. Would it be possible for me to extend the API for Godot's array class to include this function?
